# Copy Multiple Ranges using Union to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I would like to copy multiple ranges of a worksheet to a new workbook.  I have used the following codes but there is a

> run-time error "1004" - This action won't work on multiple selections

on the line `multipleRange.copy`

```
Dim Aname As String
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range, multipleRange As Range
Aname = "Report"

Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Aname & ".xls"

'Copy data to the new workbook         
With Workbooks("Assignment2_Draft").Worksheets("Main")
    Set range1 = Range("A1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set range2 = Range("J" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set range3 = Range("M1", "Q14")
    Set multipleRange = Application.Union(range1, range2, range3)

    multipleRange.Copy
End With

Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Any solutions to fix the error, thanks!

Comment: You'll need to copy each range individually

Comment: Your new workbook doesn't have a tab by the name of "Data". Also, its name isn't "Report.xlsm"

Answer (score 0):

Note that your `With` statement is not used at all, it is completely useless unless any object like a `Range` object starst with a dot `.`

This

```
Set range1 = Range("A1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

is the same as

```
Set range1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

and does not use the `With` statement. Therefore you would need to change it to

```
Set range1 = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

so every `Range`, `Rows`, `Cells` and `Columns` object that should use the `With` statement must start with a dot.

---

Also non-continous ranges can only be copied if all cells are either in one single row or in one single column. Otherwise you need to copy each range on its own.

```
With Workbooks("Assignment2_Draft").Worksheets("Main")
    Set range1 = .Range("A1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    range1.Copy
    Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'proceed with range2 and range3 one after another
End With
```